# Return MVC Json in Handsontable compatible format

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, handsontable

I'm using MVC and [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) to create an excel-like display, but I can't get the controller to return the json in a format that Handsontable can use.

The MVC Controller returns a `JsonResult`:

```
return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is the js function that returns the data:

```
function GetCategoryAttributeList() {
    var categoryattributelist = "";
    $.ajax({
         async: true,
         type: "POST",
         url: "[myurl]/PopulateHOT",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
             categoryattributelist = msg;
         }
        return categoryattributelist;
    });
```

In Firebug, I can see the returned data:

```
[{ StockCatalogueItemId=235031,  SKU="03121017593518"}, { StockCatalogueItemId=235032,  SKU="03121018032318"} ...etc
```

I call the function and assign the results to a variable:

```
var categoryattributelist = GetCategoryAttributeList();
```

Then use the results in the initialisation code:

```
var hotElement = document.getElementById('#example');
    var hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, {
        data: categoryattributelist
    });
```

At this point, the data now looks slightly different (note that 'Object' has been added before each element):

```
[Object { StockCatalogueItemId=235031,  SKU="03121017593518"}, Object { StockCatalogueItemId=235032,  SKU="03121018032318"} ...etc
```

So the current state of play is a console error and I can't seem to progress beyond this:

```
TypeError: rootElement is null
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the expected data format? Looking at [this tutorial](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.23.0/tutorial-quick-start.html), it appears to be an array or arrays (where as your returning an array of objects)

Comment: And does hard coding `var categoryattributelist = [["StockCatalogueItemId", "SKU"], [235031, 235032], ["03121017593518", "03121018032318"]];` work for you?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.23.0/tutorial-data-sources.html), it can handle all manner of data sources (including object data sources).

Comment: Hmm, no - I get the same `rootElement is null` error...

Comment: Ahh - because `hotElement` is `null` (undefined) - `getElementById('example');` - no `#` - (or use `hotElement = $('#example');`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the initialisation code within the ajax callback and see if that works

```
function GetCategoryAttributeList() {
    $.ajax({
         async: true,
         type: "POST",
         url: "[myurl]/PopulateHOT",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             //handle returned data from service
             var hotElement = $('#example');
             if(hotElement){
                 var hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, { data: data });
             }
         }
    });
```